# C# FireSharp | FileNotFoundException in client.get() method. How to resolve?

Tags: c#, firebase, console-application, visual-studio-2019, fire-sharp

I'll describe my requirements, then my problem.

The libraries I'm using are:

```
using System;
using FireSharp.Config;
using FireSharp.Response;
using FireSharp.Interfaces;
```

I want to store two fields per record in my Firebase RTDB. One is an ID (to function as the Primary Key), and the other is a Name. To do this, I created a class with these two properties as so:

```
public class Players
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

In order to insert data into my RTDB, I use the following code. *Players* in this context is the class mentioned above.

```
            Players user = new Players();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Player Tag");
            user.ID = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Player Tag");
            user.Name = Console.ReadLine();

            var set = client.Set("PlayerTag/" + user.ID, user.Name);
```

I have already configured **client** with my RTDB secret and BasePath.

This is where my issue arises. When I insert data, the program runs smoothly. It takes whatever data I give it and feeds it to the RTDB. When I check Firebase, I can find all the data I added. But when I try to *retrieve* data from the RTDB, it throws me the error.

So, here's the `get()` method:

```
            var set = client.Get("PlayerTag/" + user.ID);
            Players getuser = set.ResultAs<Players>(); //error pops up here
            
            Console.WriteLine(getuser.Name);
```

So, what happens is, basically, it highlights **Players** in the above code, and then throws me this error:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Permissions, Version=4.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

So, my question is: if it recognised the `Player` class when I run the `Set()` method, why does it return an error when I run the `Get()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your project references/packages to make sure there are no errors/warnings. The error suggests that it is missing a dll file or a reference.

Comment: So, shall I try re-installing FireSharp?

Comment: No need to reinstall the fire sharp. If you use the NuGet package manager, download the System.Security.Permissions and add it as a reference.

Comment: Yeah, that was the problem.